# Downloading from outside website root (using a href download?)

Tags: php

I'm working on file storage and my design is to display data from my database about the file along with a button fitted with an `a href` tag to download my file. I successfully do all of this when I keep my storage in my website root - but upon suggestions, i've made changes.

I now have my project root in my C:/ drive but my storage I want outside of the root but I keep my storage in my d:/ drive, per suggestions due to security - along with the fact my d:/ drive is my cloud storage anyway. From what I see online, that means I can't use `<a href="d:/storage/Username/file download>` anymore to download my file!

If that is true, how do you download from outside your website root?

And if not, how do I get past the security restrictions on downloading outside the root using my href method?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your web server software?

Comment: You usually advertise a web path to resources rather than a local file path.

Comment: I use WAMP, I code in PHP (along with JS, HTML ofc), and I store info in MYSQLDatabase

Comment: You could use a symlink.  To link from your web path to your storage.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use readfile()

either link to downloader.php?f=somefile.jpg
of use rewriterules.

in downloader.php do something like

```
<?php
$path = 'D:/map/';
if( login_check($user) && is_file($path . $_GET['f']) ) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($path . $_GET['f']);

}
?>
```

I added the login_check() because you mentioned something about security. 
Further it could be advisable to check the parameter for illegal characters (especially slashes)
And the content type may vary with chosen file

Comment: I got it to work thanks, it's not selected answer because your solution only works for jpeg's and I wanted any file to work (hence file storage, not text file storage)

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, thanks for the start from Ivo P.

I started by sending to download.php my file name, file extension, and file path all separated by * (The * is not an allowed file name). An example is:

```
download.php?f=myTextFile*txt*d:/storage/test/myTextFile.txt
```

Then, I explode $_GET['f'] by *, make sure the array is size 3, then set content headers:

```
$file_info = explode("*", $_GET['f'], 3);
if(is_file($file_info[2]) && count($file_info) == 3) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: " . mime_content_type($file_info[2]));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_info[0] . '.' .$file_info[1].'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    readfile($file_info[2]);
}
```

And that was the working solution for me! Tested on txt, jpg, and exe - works perfectly. I have other personalized for my project tests to make sure that 'f' is valid (so users can't screw it up by going to address bar and making a mess of things, see [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)) but that's the gist of it!

Edit thanks to Bjorn: Keep in mind this allows full access of server, make sure you personalize your own download.php to accept inputs following your own format (otherwise anyone could steal your php files, js files, ect!)

Comment: I hope you are aware that this enables every file on the server to be downloaded. eg `download.php?f=mySecretFile*txt*c:/private/mySecretFile.txt`

Comment: I have it restricted to only accept 'd:/storage/YourCompany/YourUserName' as the start of the string, I didn't display it in my answer to keep it less personalized. My web info (php, .htaccess, ect) is stored in c:/ -> and you can't take any files not under your username. Only logged in users can access it as well, i took that out to keep it less personalized as well